# How to determine if a UITableViewCell is being dragged?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios5, uikit

I would like to know if a cell is being dragged (via the grip on the right side when a UITableView is in editing mode). I would like to change the background while it is in that state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no callback unfortunately, but since the default behaviour is to adjust the 'alpha' value of the UITableViewCell you can check for that in '- (void)layoutSubview' of your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.alpha < 0.99) {
        // we are most likely being dragged
    } else {
        // restore for not being dragged
    }
}
```

Note that this is a bit of a hack. I noticed that this doesn't work when the table view's separatorStyle is set to 'UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible in the framework. But if it's not, you can try to override touchedMoved method in an UITableViewCell subclass?

You might then be able to also retrieve the state of your tableView (editing or not) in your UItableViewCell's custom subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes!

In ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView * myTable;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView * myScroll;
}
```

In ViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myScroll = myTable;
    myScroll.delegate = self;


}

#pragma Mark UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

That is it.

Comment: That's going to be called whenever the table view is scrolled, whether or not a cell is being dragged.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible yes! But you have to keep track on the states yourself in the view controller. Define a member 
    BOOL tableDrag = NO; 
In the method
    scrollViewWillBeginDragging
you set tableDrag = YES; And in the method
    scrollViewDidEndDragging
you set tableDraw = NO;

Now in the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method you can set the background.

If you have several scrollers then tag the scroll view so that you know which one is dragging.

Hope it helps!